# add with javascript

Tags: javascript, calculator

Can anyone help me write some JavaScript that will help me add these 2 fields if the drop down is set to yes?

Example: if txtoneside_slider = Yes then add txtoneside value to grand total

if txttwoside_slider = Yes then add txttwoside value to grand total

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/adder1999/rcU44/2/

```
<div id="onewindow">
   <label for="txtoneside" class="editor-label"><strong>1 Side</strong></label>
    <div align="right">
      <input type = "text" name = "txtoneside" id="txtoneside" value = "45" />
       <select name="txtoneside_slider" id="txtoneside_slider" data-role="slider" data-mini="true" />
         <option value="no">No</option>
         <option value="yes">Yes</option>
       </select> 
         </div>

<div id="onewindow">
   <label for="txtoneside" class="editor-label"><strong>2 Side</strong></label>
    <div align="right">
      <input type = "text" name = "txttwoside" id="txtoneside" value = "25" />
       <select name="txttwoside_slider" id="txttwoside_slider" data-role="slider" data-mini="true" />
         <option value="no">No</option>
         <option value="yes">Yes</option>
       </select> 
         </div>


<div id="grandtotal">
   <label for="txtgrandtotal" class="editor-label"><strong>JOB TOTAL</strong></label>
   <div align="right">
   <input type = "text" name = "txtgrandtotal" id="txtgrandtotal" value = "" />
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What have you tried? this task is pretty simple... but i don't feel like helping you because i think you didn't make an effort to solve this yourself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adder1999/p6q93/ this is what I have tried but I have no idea where to begin to add these values together. So I can get individual sub totals but once I have this I don't know how to add them on a yes no function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="onewindow">
   <label for="txtoneside" class="editor-label"><strong>1 Side</strong></label>
    <div align="right">
      <input type = "text" name = "txtoneside" id="txtoneside" value = "45" />
       <select name="txtoneside_slider" id="txtoneside_slider" data-role="slider" data-mini="true" onchange="javascript: if(this.value=='yes'){ document.getElementById('txtgrandtotal').value=document.getElementById('txtoneside').value;}"/>
         <option value="no">No</option>
         <option value="yes">Yes</option>
       </select> 
         </div>


<div id="onewindow">
   <label for="txtoneside" class="editor-label"><strong>2 Side</strong></label>
    <div align="right">
      <input type = "text" name = "txttwoside" id="txttwoside" value = "25" />
       <select name="txttwoside_slider" id="txttwoside_slider" data-role="slider" data-mini="true"  onchange="javascript: if(this.value=='yes'){ document.getElementById('txtgrandtotal').value= parseInt(document.getElementById('txtgrandtotal').value) + parseInt(document.getElementById('txttwoside').value);}" />
         <option value="no">No</option>
         <option value="yes">Yes</option>
       </select> 
         </div>

<div id="grandtotal">
   <label for="txtgrandtotal" class="editor-label"><strong>JOB TOTAL</strong></label>
   <div align="right">
   <input type = "text" name = "txtgrandtotal" id="txtgrandtotal" value = "" />
   </div>
 </div>
```

Maybe is what you want; it works on your fiddle.

Saludos.

Comment: Dont forgot to upvote my answer if you think that satisfied your problem xD

Comment: Is there anything to pass the decimal numbers in? Example: 134.50 it will only pass 134

Comment: Instead of parseInt use parseFloat.... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_parsefloat ...saludos ;)

Comment: You are welcome my friend....i'm glad to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

you Could implement a jquery function using [onChange](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and if the value of this is yes store the the value of the input box into a variable and if both are yes make the whatever you need with it.